# PHPUnit Segmentation fault when switching php versions

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php, php-7, php-5.6

I maintain multiple systems that require going between PHP 7.0 and PHP 5.6 constantly, I use this bash script to change versions:

```
switch-php() {
    if [[ $1 == "5.4" ]]; then
        brew unlink php55 php56 php70
        PHP_VERSION="php54"
        REPLACE=("php55" "php56" "php70")
    elif [[ $1 == "5.5" ]]; then
        brew unlink php54 php56 php70
        PHP_VERSION="php55"
        REPLACE=("php54" "php56" "php70")
    elif [[ $1 == "5.6" ]]; then
        brew unlink php54 php55 php70
        PHP_VERSION="php56"
        REPLACE=("php54" "php55" "php70")
    elif [[ $1 == "7.0" ]]; then
        brew unlink php54 php55 php56
        PHP_VERSION="php70"
        REPLACE=("php54" "php55" "php70")
    else
        echo "Unsupported php version."
        return
    fi

    brew link --overwrite $PHP_VERSION

    for OLD_VERSION in "${REPLACE[@]}"; do
        sed -i "" "s/$OLD_VERSION/$PHP_VERSION/g" /usr/local/etc/apache2/2.4/httpd.conf
    done

    sudo apachectl -k restart
}
```

I don't know why PHPUnit works properly on PHP 5.6, and when I change to PHP 7.0, I get this error:

```
PHPUnit 5.3.1 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.
[1]    11019 segmentation fault
```

It's worth saying that this PHPUnit installation is project-based and it's installed via composer.

Any ideas?

Comment: I'd suggest getting some more logging happening in PHPUnit. Does that version of PHPUnit work with PHP 7.0?

Comment: @miken32 PHPUnit 5.3.1 is indeed compatible with PHP 7.0

Answer (score 0):

Instead of sudo apachectl -k restart, try stopping Apache before the files are moved. Then start Apache after the files are moved.

Comment: What does Apache have to do with PHPUnit (which is a CLI application)?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the configuration xml file I was using caused the error. If you stumble upon the same problem, try running phpunit without custom configuration file.